# If a function $f$ is analytic in an open set $U$, then $\int_{\partial T}f(z)dz=0$ for every closed triangle $T$ in $U$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis

If a function $f$ is analytic in an open set $U$, then $\int_{\partial T}f(z)dz=0$ for every closed triangle $T$ in $U$.

I already have the result for a rectangle but how can I prove that for a triangle you also have this? What other geometric figures do you have this result for? Could anyone help me, please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Under the assumption that $U$ is simply connected, Cauchy's theorem gives you that the integral along any "nice" (rectifiable) loop in $U$ is 0.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/505939/589.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It holds for any polygon. Can you see why from this picture?

[image]

You can approximate any closed curve arbitrarily well with a polygon, so it actually holds for all closed curves "which are boundaries of subsets of $U$". (This is made precise by considering closed loops that are null-homotopic)