# How much multivariate calculus should I read to read complex integration?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, soft-question, self-learning

I do not have much knowledge in function of several variable. But I have some exams where complex analysis is needed. I started to read complex analysis but I got stuck on the proof of Cauchy's theorem because it involves Green's theorem. Then I realise that the knowledge of Multivariate calculus is essential.

That's why my question is how much Multivariate calculus is needed to read complex analysis up to integration.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

You really do not need much multivariable calculus to learn about complex analysis. Do not panic and pay attention, you will learn it easily.

Comment: But without Green's theorem how would I understand Cauchy's theorem in complex integration? @Mohammad Riazi-kermani

Comment: @cmi While a few complex analysis books (Gamelin comes to mind) prove Cauchy's theorem via Green's theorem, many prove it directly. So one solution would be to consider another book.

Comment: @cmi See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505936/cauchy-goursat-theorem-proof-without-using-vector-calculus

Comment: Can I read Complex analysis up to integration without knowing multivariate calculus a bit?@Bungo

Comment: @cmi Yes, you can. Most complex analysis books require barely any multivariable calculus, just enough to understand the difference between differentiation in $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb C$, and the Cauchy-Riemann equations. If you're not required to proceed with the book you're using, try Stein and Shakarchi, *Complex Analysis* or Ullrich, *Complex Made Simple*.