# Why did $f'$ have to be continuous in Cauchy's proof of the Cauchy-Goursat Theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

The proof that I found [here](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Ehelena/teaching/math122b/cauchygoursat.pdf) doesn't mention any requirement for $f'(z)$ to be continuous, only that it exists, for the Cauchy-Riemann Relations to hold true. Why, then, did Cauchy include this additional condition when he first proved this? Did he use a different proof altogether?
I did some searching but couldn't find this 'first proof', if it was there.

Comment: Marking as a prospective duplicate of [Cauchy-Goursat theorem, proof without using vector calculus.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505936/cauchy-goursat-theorem-proof-without-using-vector-calculus), whose answer provides a reference. (If it isn't a duplicate I'll retract the close vote.)

Comment: @Andrew D.Hwang Its helpful, but not a duplicate. It does help me understand Goursat's proof, but where in the proof I have provided in the post does it say that f' have to be continuous? I hope you're getting what I'm trying to ask, else I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: In the handout you linked, I didn't see a proof if $f'$ is not continuous...? (There wasn't exactly a proof if $f'$ _is_ continuous either, but a claim that if $f'$ is continuous then Cauchy's theorem follows from Green's theorem.) <> That said, it's possible I'm not getting what you're asking.

Comment: Green's theorem requires that the partial derivatives be continuous, so the proof of Cauchy's theorem by Green's theorem also requires an assumption of continuity of the complex derivative (which is equivalent to requiring the partial derivatives be continuous). It was much later that Goursat found a different proof of Cauchy's theorem that didn't need to assume a priori that the derivative is continuous. Cauchy cannot be blamed for not discovering the optimal proof when he first found the theorem.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks, that solves my problem'